# Shall we set experimental_aggregate_gradients to False or True when manually accumulating gradients in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning, gradient

I am trying to perform a manual gradient accumulation in **Tensorflow 2.2.0** using **Python 3.8.5**.

I have a piece of code where I gather a series of gradients( of total number of grads_total_number), in a list: `grads_list` and I do the accumulation using following code:

```
avg_accum_grads=[]    
for grad_ind in range(grads_total_number):
        avg_accum_grads.append(tf.reduce_mean(grads_list[grad_ind], axis=0))
```

I then intend to apply these grads via my optimizer to my model:

```
myopt.apply_gradients(zip(avg_accum_grads, model.trainable_variables),experimental_aggregate_gradients=True)
```

, where my optimizer is Adam defined as `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam`

However, due to the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer), I am confused if I have to set `experimental_aggregate_gradients` to False. I could not clearly understand, here that I have done the accumulation manually, if I let it be true, it continues to accumulate?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using distributed strategy .i.e. distributed training across multiple GPUs, multiple machines or TPUs, then `experimental_aggregate_gradients` parameter comes into picture. In distributed strategy, the gradients are calculated on each replica, then they are aggregated across the replicas by summing them. Aggregating across the replicas would be taken care by itself if `experimental_aggregate_gradients = True` else have to be taken care manually if `experimental_aggregate_gradients = False`. It will not make any difference if you set `experimental_aggregate_gradients` = `True` or `False` if you are not using the distributed strategy.

If you look into documentation of [tf.distribute.Strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy), you will find the below parameter,

> num_replicas_in_sync - Returns number of replicas over which gradients
> are aggregated.

To summarize, if you are using `tf.distribute.Strategy` and,

1. If `experimental_aggregate_gradients = True`, then gradients computed in different replicas are aggregated automatically.
2. If `experimental_aggregate_gradients = False`, then it's user responsibility to aggregate the gradients from the different replicas.

By default the `experimental_aggregate_gradients` is set to `True`. It wouldn't make any difference if `True` or `False` unless using `tf.distribute.Strategy`.